# How to refresh component mapping by Router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is it possible to refresh component mapping by the same routerLink? Let's say this situation:

1. I have some routing:

   ```
   const appRoutes: Routes = [
       //other Routes...
       {path: 'some/:formCode', component: SomeComponent},
       //other Routes...
   ]
   ```
2. The user enters the link `/some/dwa21e`. App loads dynamically form based on `dwa21e` code. A dynamic form (unique for code) is displayed.
3. User can complete a form. When completing the form, other action are executed in SomeComponent, but outside the form.
4. User trying submit form. There are two options:

   - **validation incorrect:** Error message is displayed. SomeComponent stays in the same state as before submit.
   - **validation correct:** SomeComponent returns to its state as in the **2.**

I have a problem with redirect to `/some/dwa21e` after correct form submit. If I trying redirect to current URL, nothing happens. **Is it possible refresh component to initial state?** Maybe, is there any other way to do this?

I would like to stress, that clearing form is not enough, because actions from **3. point**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have no idea whats wrong with the question? I ask one specific question: how can I refresh component mapping by Router to initial state. And I gave examples (in steps) to explain the issue. Please, specify what is wrong so that I can correct the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a empty route with component.
This component will redirect to `/some/dwa21e` on `ngOnInit()`;
Just send `dwa21e` parameter value to that empty component to be able to redirect to `/some` with value.

To my knowledge there is not way to refresh the component, unless you refresh the whole page.

Comment: I think, this is clever workaround. I will try and let you know if it works. Yep, I forgot to write , that refreshing whole page is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

When wanting to refresh a component, the option is given to subscribe the route params. This will enable you to trigger the code in your `ngOnInit()` again.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...
currentId: string;

constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.currentId = _route.snapshot.params['id'];
}

ngOnInit() {
    this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.currentId = params['id'];
        this.functionToLoad();
    }
}
```